# Reading contact details from blackberry cell

Tags: blackberry

how can i read  read contact details from blackberry cell?
can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this website: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javasdk5.jsp

Use this library

**Multiple ContactList Support**: new API supports multiple Personal Information Management (PIM) data sources. It allows third-party developers to use existing PIM APIs to access and query each individual address book on a BlackBerry smartphone.

Hope that helps
Let me know if it does.

**PK**